# Installing Fore's New Idles in Skyrim (FNIS) on Linux using Wine/PlayOnLinux

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, linux, wine

I'm a user of PlayOnLinux/Wine and I need to know how to install FNIS for my Skyrim. I can run GenerateFNISForUsers.exe using POL but there are no patches available. What do I do?

I don't know if I'll survive without the Alive Peeing mod, haha.

Answer (score 2):

As of Wine 1.8, I don't see any way you can.

Wine Mono isn't complete enough to run it.

Installing .Net 4.0 gets closer as it lets you start the program.

However it then doesn't work because the .Net function that FNIS calls to read the animation files uses some obscure Windows function that Wine does not provide.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using FNIS without problems with wine 1.9.5 and above sense October of last year.

One has to manually install FNIS by moving the apporite files from the main zip file to the correct directories under Skyrim. The other FNIS optional packages can be installed under Mod Orginisor. You can use the STEP wiki page for more info about FNIS. http://wiki.step-project.com/Fores_New_Idles_in_Skyrim